# Retry failed Cron Task on Google Appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

There're a  very helpful feature of Push Queue Task:

> If the task returns a status code outside of this range, App Engine retries the task until it succeeds.

But seems that it's not the same for Cron Task. As I see from my logs, if a Cron Task failed with 500 status code, Appengine doesn't try to retry this task.

I know that I can configure it for standard Queue ([Configuring_Retry_Attempts_for_Failed_Tasks](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/queue#Configuring_Retry_Attempts_for_Failed_Tasks)), and wondering, can I make such configuration for Cron tasks? Like a configuration for a queue named `__cron`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot, but you can invoke a task queue from your cron, and then configure that task queue as necessary.

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18003474/which-task-queue-does-app-engine-cron-use) with the response below, and I have experimented enough with GAE cron to confirm that it does have the same configurability as a task queue.

> [GAE cron] doesn't use a task queue, and the retry options for cron 'tasks'
>   aren't configurable. The closest you can get is to do nothing in your
>   cron 'task' except enqueue another task, which can be configured via a
>   queue.