# Which task queue does App Engine cron use?

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, task-queue

The Google App Engine [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron) says:

> The App Engine Cron Service allows you to configure regularly
>   scheduled tasks...

But what task queue do cron scheduled tasks run on?  How can I change the task queue for a cron job?  My motivation for this question is that I'd like to control the retry-parameters of cron scheduled tasks.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't use a task queue, and the retry options for cron 'tasks' aren't configurable. The closest you can get is to do nothing in your cron 'task' except enqueue another task, which can be configured via a queue.

Comment: Clearly and concisely answered, and an alternative to boot.  Thanks.